# How to sum hours and minutes with Sumif if condition is meet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The following formula sum time values from a column if 3 conditions are meet, then convert the resulting value into hour. But the minutes are missing. If I could write something in this logic `hour-and-minute(L2:L)`, instead of `hour(L2:L)` it would work.

```
=MAP(H2:H,O2:O,M2:M,N2:N,P2:P,LAMBDA(Employee,Week,Payment,Month,Year,IF(ISBLANK(Employee),,SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(hour(L2:L),H2:H=Employee,O2:O=Week,N2:N=Month,P2:P=Year))))))
```

Note: L Column are populated with time values in the format "hh:mm"

Exemple sheet:
The formula I'm using would outputs 03:00 for Billy on Total time, because it's considering only the hour and ignoring the minutes by using `hour(L2:L)`

```
Animals   Month     Week         Time      Total time
Billy    January      1          02:30        03:30
Billy    January      1          01:00        03:30
Maggie   January      1          08:00      08:00
```

Comment: First filter L column then apply `hour` and `minute` function and sum.

Comment: It's pretty hard to figure out what you're doing when you're referencing columns such as `L` but no spreadsheet/sample to cross-reference exactly what is happening in your sheet. Use a [Mark down table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) and show what you have and what you expect to be returned in your formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the time to a fraction with [`TIMEVALUE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267350), sum it, then convert it back using [`TEXT()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139).

So pretty much change this part:

```
SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(hour(L2:L),H2:H=Employee,O2:O=Week,N2:N=Month,P2:P=Year)))
```

To this:

```
TEXT(SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(TIMEVALUE(L2:L),H2:H=Employee,O2:O=Week,N2:N=Month,P2:P=Year))), "[h]:mm")
```

And the full formula:

```
=MAP(H2:H,O2:O,M2:M,N2:N,P2:P,LAMBDA(Employee,Week,Payment,Month,Year,IF(ISBLANK(Employee),,TEXT(SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(TIMEVALUE(L2:L),H2:H=Employee,O2:O=Week,N2:N=Month,P2:P=Year))), "[h]:mm"))))
```

Note that the hour format uses square brackets `[]` to count the full time duration, otherwise it will wrap around after 24 hours. You can find the full list of formats [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#date_time_format_tokens).